# CircuitPython & ESP32-S2-Saola boards returning code 43 errors

Tags: usb, esp32, python

I am currently trying to connect to some ESP32-S2-Saola devboards that are running CircuitPython 6.1.0 via the USB OTG pins, but the device shows up as as "Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)", and I see the following error in Windows' Device Manager:

```
Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)
A request for the USB device descriptor failed.
```

The boards I tried are manufactured by Espressif and are powered by the ESP32-S2-WROOM and ESP32-S2-WROVER.

I flashed it with the following command taken from the official Adafruit website and using Espressif's tools from their GitHub repository:
`python esptool.py -b esp32s2 --port COMx --after=no_reset write_flash 0x0 <firmware.bin>`

I didn't notice any error during the flashing process, the hash of the flashed firmware was verified properly, and the onboard LED is slowly flashing green which indicates that the main code file has finished executing according to CircuitPython's documentation.

The serial terminal  on the main USB port also doesn't return any error:

```
ESP-ROM:esp32s2-rc4-20191025
Build:Oct 25 2019
rst:0x1 (POWERON),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3ffe6100,len:0x4
load:0x3ffe6104,len:0x19d0
load:0x4004c000,len:0x162c
load:0x40050000,len:0x20fc
entry 0x4004c30c
```

I've tried the following things to attempt to fix the issue without any success:

- Using 15cm/8cm cables or jumpers to connect the data pins.
- Inserting the USB cable slowly into the host device to connect D+ and D- after the device booted
- Using different breakout boards
- Adding 2 10ohms resistors in series on the D+ and D- line to vaguely match the missing 22ohms resistors
- Testing the 6.2.0-beta3 release of CircuitPython.
- Using different USB cables that have the D+ and D- wires
- Checking that the USB pins from the chip go to the right pins on the booard with a multimeter and through the schematics
- Tying the ID pin to GND
- Swapping the D+ and D- pins

I don't know if I'm missing something or if my boards have a problem since the official documentation doesn't really offer any help in terms of troubleshooting.

Comment: Are you connecting the USB via a hub? If so, what spec? USB 1/2/3?

Comment: @Kartman I tried connecting it through a USB 3.0 port directly on the laptop and though a USB 2.0 hub on the same port.
Are the USB 3.0 ports less tolerant to noise and things like that compared to the 1.x/2.0 ones ?